# UK Visa financial support

Tags: visas, uk

I am applying for UK visa to take an exam.My saving account doesn't contain enough money, though I have saving certificates with monthly interest that worth lot more than what I am expected to expend. My questions: 1-Can I use those saving certificate as an evidence that I have enough money ,bearing in mind that I can encash them with notice?
2- Is it a good idea to redeem some of the certificates to enhance the account or they will consider it as funds parking?

Comment: ‘Funds parking’ refers to money that is not genuinely available to the applicant but has been provided by a 3rd party specifically to make the applicant’s financial position appear better than it really is. If the savings certificates are in your name then you cannot be ‘funds parking’ and using them as evidence of your general financial standing is valid. If you need the liquidity for your trip, stating that you will encash after receiving your visa seems reasonable and avoids a potential loss of interest on the investment if your application is refused.

Comment: @Traveller, please [make that comment an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘Funds parking’ refers to money that is not genuinely available to the applicant but has been provided by a 3rd party specifically to make the applicant’s financial position appear better than it really is. If the savings certificates are in your name then you cannot be ‘funds parking’, and using them as evidence of your general financial standing is valid. If you need the liquidity for your trip, stating that you will encash after receiving your visa seems reasonable and avoids a potential loss of interest on the investment if your application is refused (note: this assumes the notice period on the certificate(s) expires before your expected travel date).

Comment: first, thank you for your elaboration, no the notice period on the certificates doesn't expires before my expected travel date. you think I should encash them first before applying, and demonstrate that the cash in my account is from previously owned certificates?!

Comment: If you can encash them at any moment, showing (proof of) the certificates will be enough, even when doing so is at a cost. Encashing them at a loss will not strengthen your position.

Comment: Sorry for being obsessive, but what I got from your comment is that: I should apply regardless of the cash in my account as long as I clearly demonstrate in my cover letter the possession of certificates, with documents to prove that, that I will encash when I get my visa. Did I get that right ?

Comment: @DR.AhmedAmer Yes, providing you meet the other requirements (ties to home country etc) and the time needed to organize the encash meant fits in with the start date of your trip.