# Reapply to a UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

My application for a short visit visa to the UK was refused because of insufficient cash in my bank account on 21/06/2018. However, I have some saving certificates which were redeemed on 17/06/2018, increasing my account threefold.

How long should I wait before reapplying, as long as I will provide bank statements supporting that this money was already in my account in form of saving certificates and not a form of funds parking?

[image]

Comment: @D.R.AhmedAmer Why didn’t you include evidence of your savings certificates with your first application? See your earlier question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112598/uk-visa-financial-support

Comment: I had, but he/she totally neglected them!. I think he/she never looked at my cover letter.

Comment: What is your evidence that the agent 'neglected the savings certificates'?

Comment: The fact that he mentioned I am spending all my savings, while the saving certificates worth more than 14 folds compared to the trip expenture

Comment: To be clear, did you enter the amount of your savings certificates in the relevant section of the application and include certified evidence of their existence, or did you just mention them in your covering letter?

Comment: The application didn't have any field about your cash or certificates, only what you earn, living expenses and the expected cost of trip. So, I had to explain everything in my cover letter and I did include formal evidence of the certificates.

Comment: @DR.AhmedAmer There is a question ‘Do you have any other income or savings’ in the application. The online form is pretty comprehensive, there really shouldn’t be a need to explain everything in a lengthy cover letter

Comment: In your earlier question here, it was suggested that those deposits could be seen as funds parking. This small excerpt of the refusal suggests it may be more than that: financial stability and missing information. Cover letters can't be used to explain missing supporting documents.

Comment: @traveller Sorry I forgot that however I did include the certificates. I can send you a copy of my application

Comment: @Giorgio So what you are saying is that because I am spending all the money in the account, he thinks that is funds parking?!

Comment: @Giorgio BTW the bank statement clearly stated that the money came from  redeeming certificates. I also provided documentation of the  rest of the certificates

Comment: @DR.AhmedAmer The letter states quite plainly: You waste your entire savings for a short visit to the UK. The immigration officer believes not fully unjustified that nobody who does not intend to stay illegally in the UK and try to find work does that.